# htaccess mod rewrite - force www on domain only but not subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I am wanting to force the www. on the main domain only, but leave it off all subdomains.
This is the code i have so far, which works, but doesnt work on subfolders.

The domain i am using  is a .co.uk

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.[^.]+\.[^.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

domain.co.uk redirects to www.domain.co.uk and sub.domain.co.uk doesnt (which is correct)
but domain.co.uk/folder/ doesnt redirect to www.domain.co.uk/folder/

Answer (score 1):

Try using `%{REQUEST_URI}` instead of `$1` as `$1` might be different depending upon the directory of `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.co\.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
```

Also make sure this is very first rule in your .htaccess.

Comment: This doesnt work any better than what i posted originally, subfolders still do not force the www.

Comment: You need to make sure that this is very first rule in your root htaccess.

Comment: Yes, this is the very first rule, and its on the root. It doesnt work for subfolders, it only works for the root domain without any subfolder.

Comment: Rule is 100% correct and working on many of my live sites/blogs. Are you sure you're using Apache? Try to test in a new browser with only this rule in your .htaccess

Comment: Yes it is apache and this is the only rule in my htaccess other than 
Options -Indexes, which is on line 4. It works and is using the rule correctly, but only on domain.co.uk. If i write domain.co.uk/folder it doesnt add the www.

Comment: ok verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting same garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not? If you get 500 then enable `RewriteLog` from Apache and provide log messages for this redirect.